# Numpy array indexing with indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I wrote the following:

```
arr3=np.array([[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],[[2,2,3],[4,2,3],[4,2,2],[2,2,2]],[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]])
```

As I expected,
`arr3[0:3,1]` should return the same result as
 `arr3[0:3][1]`:`array([[2, 2, 3],[4, 2, 3],[4, 2, 2],[2, 2, 2]])`

But it returns:`array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 2, 3],[1, 1, 1]])`.

BTW, I am using python3 in Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing `arr3[0:3,1]`, you are taking element from `0:3` in the first `axis` and then for each of those, taking the first `element`.

This gives a different result to taking the `0:3` in the first axis with `arr3[0:3]` and then taking the first `array` from this `axis`.

So in this case, the `0:3` part does nothing in either case as the `array's` shape is `(3, 4, 3)` so taking the `first` `3` just gives you back the same `array`. This does absolutely nothing in the second case, but in the first case, it does serve as essentially a place holder so that you can access the second `axis`, but for that you should just use a colon so: `[:, some_index]`.

See how its the same `array`?

```
>>> arr3[0:3]
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[2, 2, 3],
        [4, 2, 3],
        [4, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]]])
```

But then when you do `arr3[:, 1]` you are taking the second element from the **second** `axis` of the `array` so that will give you:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 2, 3],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

whereas in the other case, you are taking the second element from the **first** `axis` of the array` so:

```
array([[2, 2, 3],
       [4, 2, 3],
       [4, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```

---

To read further about `numpy` `indexing`, take a look at [`this page on scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Take note of this specific description which applies directly to your problem:

> When there is at least one slice `(:)`, ellipsis `(...)` or `np.newaxis` in the index (or the array has more dimensions than there are advanced indexes), then the behaviour can be more complicated. **It is like concatenating the indexing result for each advanced index element**

Comment: @kylechan Please `accept` (grey tick next to answer) and `upvote` if you haven't already

Comment: done!  my first time to use stackoverflow. thanks for being patient

Comment: @kylechan No problem, this was a well worded question for a new user :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at our multidimensional numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
arr3=np.array([
    [
        [1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]
    ],[
        [2,2,3],[4,2,3],[4,2,2],[2,2,2]
    ],[
        [1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]
    ]
])
print(arr3[0:3,1])
```

That returns:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 2 3]
 [1 1 1]]
```

Which makes sense because we are fetching row numbers 1 through 3 and we are grabbing only the first column.

However, `arr3[0:3][1]` returns the array from row 0 to row 3 and then selects the second row (or row index 1).

Observe:

```
print(arr3[0:3])
```

Returns:

```
[[[1 2 3]
  [1 2 3]
  [1 2 3]
  [1 2 3]]

 [[2 2 3]
  [4 2 3]
  [4 2 2]
  [2 2 2]]

 [[1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]]]
```

It returns the a new array (which happens to be the same as our current array because we just asked for all rows in the array).  Then we ask for the second row:

```
print(arr3[0:3][1])
```

Returns:

```
[[2 2 3]
 [4 2 3]
 [4 2 2]
 [2 2 2]]
```